# How to do relative node ordering using Neo4J Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm building a Maven dependency graph using Neo4J. One of the queries I need to support is finding all nodes that depend on a particular dependency. So if C depends on B and A, and B depends on A, `findByDependency(A)` should return B and C. I implemented this using the following query, and it's working:

```
MATCH (v1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(v2)
WHERE EXISTS (v1.gav) AND v2.gav = "A"
RETURN DISTINCT v1.gav
```

However, in my example above, C also depends on B in addition to depending on A. I'd like the result set to be sorted such that B comes before C. I can do this in code, but is there a way to do it using Cypher?

Comment: Are circular dependencies possible (e.g. if B depended on C as well as A)? If so, then there would be no single ordering.

Comment: @cybersam Circular dependencies are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then you need to calculate the interdependence of the nodes:

```
MATCH (v1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(v2 {gav: 'A'}) WHERE EXISTS(v1.gav)
OPTIONAL MATCH (v1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-(v3)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(v2) WHERE EXISTS(v3.gav)
WITH DISTINCT v1.gav AS gav, 
     COUNT(v3) AS sortValue
RETURN gav 
ORDER BY sortValue DESC
```

**Update**: Another way:

```
MATCH p = (v1)-[:DEPENDS_ON*1..2]->(v2 {gav: 'A'}) 
    WHERE ALL(n IN NODES(p)[0..-1] WHERE EXISTS(n.gav))
WITH DISTINCT v1.gav AS gav, 
     SUM(LENGTH(p)) AS sortValue
RETURN gav 
ORDER BY sortValue ASC
```

Comment: This seems to be working. I'm going to accept your answer, but for learning purposes, is there a way to do this using path length, something like [this](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/05/19/neo4j-finding-all-shortest-paths/)?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Look update (I can not test now, but should work)