# Node ranking in Neo4J Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

This is a follow up of my question [How to do relative node ordering using Neo4J Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48635710/839733). I accepted the answer there, but later realized that my use case is more involved. Following is an piece of the graph I'm working with, with the desired node ordering shown in the table. Clearly, I should be ordering by indegree, but for *nodes with the same indegree*, relationships between them need to be considered (nodes `S` and `A` in the graph). Cycles are not allowed.

How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: According to your visualization, the indegree of S is 2, not 1.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "relationships between them need to be considered"? Considered in what way?

Comment: @cybersam you’re right, S indegree is 2. What I mean by relationships need to be considered is that if they have the same indegree, but one has a dependency on the other, the dependent one should rank lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do the job (thanks to [this](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/)). I'm new to Cypher and Neo4J, thus, other answers are welcome, as well as comments about the following if it may not work in some case.

```
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a:App)-[:DEPENDS_ON*0..10]->(b:App))
WHERE a <> b
WITH b.name as bn, count(p) AS c
WITH COLLECT({name:bn, count:c}) AS paths
MATCH (a:App) WHERE NOT ()-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(a)
WITH paths + COLLECT({name:a.name, count:0}) AS allPaths
UNWIND allPaths AS path
WITH path.name AS name, path.count AS count
RETURN name, count
ORDER BY count DESC
```

For the aforementioned graph, the query above produces the following results:

```
╒═════════╤═══════╕
│"name"   │"count"│
╞═════════╪═══════╡
│"C"      │4      │
├─────────┼───────┤
│"S"      │3      │
├─────────┼───────┤
│"A"      │1      │
├─────────┼───────┤
│"GW"     │0      │
├─────────┼───────┤
│"GC"     │0      │
└─────────┴───────┘
```